Create a tournament for multiplayer games and book the slot using native coin
I need some help with a issue that I have. I will create a web site in that a tournaments page for major games like CS, PUGB, Fortnite etc.
For example:

Fortnite Tournament  Registration end xx.xx.xxxx @ xx:xx Event start xx.xx.xxxx @ xx:xx available places xx.

The players/users have to pay a fee example 1000 Xcoin and it will automatically book his place in the tournament. Probably I need a registration page first with name, game tag, email and wallet address so they will receive the confirmation after the payment is done. The winner will take 60% - Charity wallet 20% and Administration fee 20%.
Is this possible? Wallet integration and smart contract for the bookings and reserve his place in the tournament.
Any thoughts?
I didn't try yet; I can take manual payments and send a manual confirmation with venue date and time and server details and password but something automatically will be great.
